# How to Log service response in a single file

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service. I have this operation that logs any request that comes in to the the service. The problem I have here is that it logs each request in a separate file. How can I log everything in a single file separating each log with a single line?

I wanted to log it in one file for a performance reason.

```
      public byte sendMessage(string strMsgId, string strMessage)
        {
        byte result = 1;
        try
        {
            if (strMsgId == "02") 
            {
                // Logging---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Build timestamp string
                var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hhmmssfff");

                // Build filename for Inbound messages, concat timestamp and .txt extension.
                string debugFileName = "C:\\Inboundmessage" + " " + timeStampString + ".txt";
                var inboundMessageLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
                // Write to the file:
                inboundMessageLog.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("Time = {0}", currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt"));
                inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", "Inbound Message:", Environment.NewLine, strMessage.Substring(1016, 26));
                inboundMessageLog.Close();

                // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                result = 0;
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            //Failed
            result = 1;
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: Log to a database instead. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do as @Sudhakar and Joel said, and wrap `StreamWriter` in `using` contruct:

```
 using (var inboundMessageLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default)) {  
    // Write to the file:  
    inboundMessageLog.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);  
    inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("Time = {0}", currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt"));  
    inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", "Inbound Message:", Environment.NewLine, strMessage.Substring(1016, 26));  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from:

```
 string debugFileName = "C:\\Inboundmessage" + " " + timeStampString + ".txt";
 var inboundMessageLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

to:

```
 string debugFileName = "C:\\Inboundmessage.txt";
 var inboundMessageLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, true, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public StreamWriter(
    string path,
    bool append,
    Encoding encoding
)
```

> append Type: System.Boolean true to append data to the file; false to
>   overwrite the file. If the specified file does not exist, this
>   parameter has no effect, and the constructor creates a new file.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

in your current code you are changing the filename with latest timestamp for every log entry.

`StreamWriter()` method first checks whether given file exists or not , if the file does not exist it creates a new file.

in your case as you are changing the filename for every log entry it could notbe found and creates the new file everytime.

**Solution 1:**

You can create a variable to store the path of the file `(debugFileName)` on above the function with fixed filename (ex: `myLog.txt`) as class variable and use the same in your `sendMessage()` function and change the append attribute of the `StreamWriter()` constructor to `true` to append the contents instead of overwriting th old contents of the file for every log entry.

From MSDN: [`StreamWriter Constructor (String, Boolean, Encoding)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class for the specified
>   file by using the specified encoding and default buffer size. If the
>   file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file
>   does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.

**Suggestion :** you are using `StremWriter` which implements the `IDisposable` Interface so you can enclose its declaration within a `using {}` block to ensure its(object)  disposal after leaving the using block.

**Note :** if you are using using{} block you dont need to call `Close()` function on StreamWriter object as it will be taken care by `using{}` block.

Try This:

```
 string debugFileName = "C:\\myLog.txt";//declare this as class variable
 public byte sendMessage(string strMsgId, string strMessage)
    {
    byte result = 1;
    try
    {
        if (strMsgId == "02") 
        {                
           // Build timestamp string
           var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
           string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hhmmssfff");
           using(var inboundMessageLog = new StreamWriter(debugFileName, true, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
          {
            // Write to the file:
            inboundMessageLog.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("Time = {0}", currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt"));
            inboundMessageLog.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", "Inbound Message:", Environment.NewLine, strMessage.Substring(1016, 26));


            // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            result = 0;
          }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Failed
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;  
   }
```

**Solution 2:** if you dont want to deal with object disposal issues you can simply use the Static class System.IO.File class to write the File contents.

```
 string debugFileName = "C:\\myLog.txt";  //declare this as class variable
 public byte sendMessage(string strMsgId, string strMessage)
    {
    StringBuilder strLines=new StringBuilder();
    byte result = 1;
    try
    {
        if (strMsgId == "02") 
        {                
            // Build timestamp string
            var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string timeStampString = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hhmmssfff");

            // Write to the file:
            strLines.Append(DateTime.Now+Environment.NewLine);
            strLines.Append("Time = {0}"+Environment.NewLine, currentDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff tt"));
            strLines.Append("{0}{1}{2}"+Environment.NewLine, "Inbound Message:", Environment.NewLine, strMessage.Substring(1016, 26));                

            File.WriteAllText(debugFileName , str.ToString());
            result = 0;
          }

    }
    catch
    {
        //Failed
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above responses would solve your problem. The other problem that'll hit you in the long run would be because you are breaking ***Single Responsibility Principle***.

The WCF service should just serve the request. Logging is a different functionality.

Had I been working with you I would have recommended to pull of logging all together to a different class and leave an abstraction in the service.

```
public interface ILogger
{
    bool LogMessage(string message, SeverityEnum severity..etc);
}

public class Service: IService
{
     ILogger logger;
     public Service(ILogger logger)
     {
            //check if logger is not null
            this.logger = logger;
     }
}
```

use the extensions of WCF to insert logger dependency and take loggin functionality away from WCF.

You'll need a service host factory and Dependeny Injection provide to achieve rest of the functionality.

But once you would be in total control of how the logging works for you.

All the best

Zia